# How to get facebook users' public statuses using facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, status

I'm trying to get users' public status with my app_token *(so no one need to be authenticated)* but running `GET /[user_id]/statuses` return empty array *(not for my account)*.

this is while running `GET /[user_id]/feed` and `GET /[user_id]/posts`, both return public entries in user's wall *(such as shared links and shared photos)* except statuses *(what user posted on his/her wall)*

according to facebook graph api, accessing to `statuses` object need `read_stream` permission; so I also tried create another token with my facebook account, but still empty array would return.

I think when a public status will be shown, even to unregistered users, there must have to be a way to get them via graph api.

Any idea guys?

P.S: I also tried with access_token with `friend_status` permission but no difference

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_OR_USER_ID/statuses?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN works fine if you have a valid access token.